# Using JQuery to get the default value of a textarea, clearing onfocus and reinstating value on empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have some JQuery that isn't working and I need a little help.  I a few forms on my website, and they all have a textarea with the class ".form-textarea".  What I'm trying to do is use JQuery to get the default value of the textarea, clear the value on focus and reinstate the original value if the the textarea is empty. I realise that an ID would probably be better but I need a generic function to affect all of the textareas with this particular class.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var def = $(".form-textarea")
$(".form-textarea").focus(function(srcc)
{
  if ($(this).val() == def)
    {
      $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
      $(this).val("");
    }
});

$(".form-textarea").blur(function()
{
  if ($(this).val() == "")
    {
      $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
      $(this).val(def);
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur();        
});
```

Comment: Can you show us a link where this code is running on a form?

Comment: you may need something like the jquery identify plugin to keep track of textarea - default value association

Comment: Hi John, I appreciate the advice so thanks but I only accept if there's an answer that's acceptable. Your answer has been severely accepted, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old method I used for the exact same purpose. I believe this is what you're looking for (uses Textareas) : **[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DpGKN/2/)**

This uses the jQuery data API. I've also added an extra class so you can markup your text nicely (disabled_text). This is a general purpose method so all you need to do is add the `suggest` class to your textarea/input and the script will do the rest

```
<textarea class='suggest'>Some default value</textarea>
<textarea class='suggest'>Some default value2</textarea>
<textarea class='suggest'>Some default value3</textarea>
<input type='text' value ='me too' class='suggest'>

$('.suggest').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
    if ($this.val() != '') {
        return;
    }
    $this.data('defaultval', $this.val());

    $this.addClass('disabled_text').focus(function() {

        if ($this.val() == $this.data('defaultval')) {
            $this.val('');

        }
        $this.removeClass('disabled_text');
    }).blur(function() {
        var oldVal = ($this.data('defaultval')) ? $this.data('defaultval') : '';
        if ($this.val() == '' && oldVal != '') {
            $this.addClass('disabled_text').val(oldVal);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: JohnP, that's perfect.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here, give this a whirl and see if it does the trick.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $default = "defaultText";

    $(".form-textarea").focus(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == $default ){
            $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $(".form-textarea").blur(function(){
        if( $(this).val() == "" ){
            $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
            $(this).val($default);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input class="form-textarea" type="text" value="defaultText" />
<input class="form-textarea" type="text" value="defaultText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried to remove the value "srcc" from the focus function and it works fine